# Why does Queue has methods that throw exceptions while other Collection's classes don't?

Tags: java, collections, queue

I came back to revising *Collection framework in Java*. The thing I always knew but never understood is why do `Queue` implementations have methods that *throw exceptions*?

So there is `add()`, `element()` and `remove()` that *throw exceptions* and on other side `offer()`, `peek()` and `poll()` that *return special values*. In **List**, **Set** and **Map** there was never such an option - we just had methods that return some value and never throw an exception.

My simple question is why? Howcome is `Queue` this special that has more versatile methods, while other *Collection Interfaces* have only 'return type methods'? What could I be missing?

Comment: Did you check the java docs ? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html

Comment: It's considered a different [data structure](http://homes.sice.indiana.edu/yye/lab/teaching/spring2014-C343/lists.php), therefore different methods. People seem to want queues and lists, not just queues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot speak on behalf of the language/data structures designers but, I assume it is because of the difference in nature on the use of the objects you are comparing.

Objects like **Set**, **Map** or **List** are designed to contain information but the **Queue** object is designed for holding elements prior to processing and, in addition to the basic collection operations, it adds some additional operations to help with that processing.

At processing time, some situations may require or can cause the queue to be empty and that is the expected behaviour, on those situations having a method that does not throw an exception is appropriate and useful. On other situations, developers can consider the queue being empty as an exceptional circumstance and, an exception is appropriate.